# Getting ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: while inserting data using ROR

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

I am getting the following error while inserting the data into database through rails console using ROR.

Error:

```
irb(main):004:0> book.comments << comment
   (1.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `book_id`
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4
.2.5.1/lib/active_record/attribute.rb:138:in `with_value_from_database'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4
.2.5.1/lib/active_record/attribute_set.rb:39:in `write_from_user'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4
.2.5.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/write.rb:74:in `write_attribute_with_
type_cast'
```

Here I am trying to link one table (comments) with another table (books) by inserting some data. My code flow is below:

```
irb(main):004:0>book=Book.find(1)
comment = Comment.new :text => "This is an comment", :author => "Adam"
book.comments << comment
```

.......create_comments.rb:

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.text :text
      t.string :author
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

book.rb:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments
end
```

comment.rb:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :book
end
```

While I am executing the last line this error is coming.

Comment: does the Comment model have a book_id field?

Comment: No,it has only two field(`i.e-text,author`).

Comment: @satya : show your both model's association

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not `book_id` column in your comments table.

Follow this below steps:

1. `rails g migration AddBookToComments book:references`

which will create a migration file as:

```
class AddBookToComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :comments, :book, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

2. run `rake db:migrate`
3. add `book_id` in strong paremeters in **comments_controller.rb**

Then try:

```
> book=Book.find(1)
> comment = book.comments.new(:text => "This is an comment", :author => "Adam")
> comment.save!
```

Comment: when i execute your second command its throwing this `
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked: ALTER TABLE "comments" ADD "book_id"
 integer` error.

Comment: after executing your 1st command its gave this line ` add_reference :comments, :book, index: true, foreign_key: true`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114025/discussion-between-satya-and-gagan-gami).